# How to get rid of empty strings from csv file's row using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing code which takes rows from a CSV file and transfers them into a lists of integers. However, if I leave some blank entries in the row, I get a "list index out of range" error. Here is the code:

```
import csv

with open('Test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    rows = [[int(row[0]), int(row[1]),int(row[2]),int(row[3])] for row in reader]


for row in rows:
   print(row)
```

I looked up some similar questions on this website and the best idea for the solution I got was:

```
rows = [[int(row[0]), int(row[1]),int(row[2]),int(row[3])] for row in reader if len(row)>1]
```

However, it resulted with the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you don't have an int or it is empty the cast will fail.

The below example inserts a zero '0' in case the value is not an int or is empty. Replace it by what you want.

You can optimize the code but this should work:

**Edit**: Shorter version

```
import csv

def RepresentsInt(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
l = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        l.append([int(r) if RepresentsInt(r) else 0 for r in row])

for row in l:
   print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works just fine. Quick question if I would like to get rid of zeros in each row,what would I need to add. I tried ` for i in row: if i==0: row remove i`.

Comment: I meant ` for i in row: if row[i]==0: row remove (row[i])`.

Comment: What do you mean, whenever there is no data, instead of adding a 0 (zero), add/show something else in the list? If so what do you want to add?

Comment: Never mind. I found a way.( row=[x for x in row if x!=0]). Thanks again!